# Version of report Server Database is either in a format that is not valid or it can not be read. Expected version is '162'

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Trying to setup a SharePoint servers with SharePoint 2013 and SQL 2012 SP1. I have installed SQL Server 2012 with SharePoint mode on Db server and SharePoint 2013 is installed on Front end server. I have installed SharePoint RS add-in on Front end server as well.

[image]

In the Service application settings for SQL Reporting Server whenever I click on System Settings, I get below error.
The Version of report Server Database is either in a format that is not valid or it can not be read. Expected version is '162'
[image]

Can you please advice on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Just got it resolved..if it will help anyone

I had to delete the existing Service Application for Reporting services and re-create it and point to existing Reporting db and everything started to work normally